# How to change background colour on each page with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sass

I have a black background setup on the body in my global.css that I'm using for most of my pages, but for a few pages I would like to change the background colour.
Can't manage to do it...

I tried "style jsx global" within the pages I want the background to be different but the background is first black then turn to the new colour.

Advices?

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.